# Surface custom exception messages in SQL Server MDS from a user defined business rule action stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I've created a stored procedure that is run as a user defined action for a business rule in MDS. I want to be able to surface up the exceptions I have put in the procedure to be visible to the user executing the business rule as a result of their modification.

It seems like in MDS' built in procedures, e.g. `[mdm].[udpValidateEntity]` they have used:

```
RAISERROR (N'MDSERR200226|The entity version cannot be validated. It is the target of a sync relationship.', 16, 1);
```

This, if copied and pasted in my code results in an expected error popup msg

> 200226:The entity version cannot be validated. It is the target of a sync relationship.

But when I try to implement this using my own error code and message

```
IF @err_msg IS NOT NULL
BEGIN;
    SET @err_msg = N'MDSERR99999|MDS PROC usr.UpdateInvalidValidityRange' + @err_msg;
    RAISERROR (@err_msg, 16, 1);
END;
```

The error message gets replaced by a generic error message:

> 99999: A database error has occurred. Contact your system administrator.

Is there a way to surface error messages to the UI?

Comment: Could be worth querying `sys.messages` to see if they've added custom messages in there, i.e.: there may be message_id 200226 rows present for various languages.

Comment: Don't seem to have those codes in sys.messages or sys.sysmessages, sadly.